# creating an AttributeStatement and AuthnStatement node with Kentor AuthServices

Tags: saml-2.0, kentor-authservices

new to Saml2, I want to use the Kentor AuthServices .net library for generating a Saml2 response, I have checked the output xml and I can't find any node for either "AttributeStatement" or "AuthnStatement".
Does anyone knows how can I deal with them on the library?
Cheers
H

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The support in the `Saml2Response` class in [Kentor.AuthServices](https://github.com/KentorIT/authservices) for sending responses is very limited at the moment, so there is <del>no support for `AttributeStatement` nor</del> for `AuthnStatement`. *Support for sending `AttributeStatement` has been added*.

Support might be added in a future release, but the main focus of the Kentor.AuthServices library is to be *service provider* that receives and parses SAML2 responses. The identity provider functionality for sending saml2 responses is of much lower priority.

If you need it, please add an issue on GitHub to get it into the backlog, or implement the features yourself and send a pull request. Pull requests are always welcome :-)

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the response, i think that Ill give it a go trying to implement it by myself

Comment: Good luck, please open on issue on GitHub if there's anything with the implementation that you want to discuss or if you need help getting started with the development.